# How can I remove ?p=$page_name to SEO friendly url for my website?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a url like below:

```
http://localhost/tapromtour.com/image_detail?page=2&id=23&ti=save-visit
```

I want to have an output like this

```
http://localhost/tapromtour.com/image_detail/2/23/save-visit.html
```

or

```
http://localhost/tapromtour.com/image_detail/2/23/save-visit
```

I can only do it with only one level (index.php?p=page_name). How can I do it with my .htaccess file.
This is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^inc/.*$ index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]


ErrorDocument 400 /.error.php
ErrorDocument 401 /.error.php
ErrorDocument 403 /.error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /.error.php
ErrorDocument 405 /.error.php
ErrorDocument 408 /.error.php
ErrorDocument 414 /.error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /.error.php
ErrorDocument 502 /.error.php
ErrorDocument 504 /.error.php

DirectoryIndex index.htm index.html index.shtml index.php default.php .index.php
```